# How to print the all the elements of String type arrays which present inside an list?

Tags: java, arraylist, dynamic-arrays

```
public class list{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        //Dynamic arraylist in which is input is dynamic like below is example

         ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
          rows.add(new String[]{"1","2","3"});
          rows.add(new String[]{"1","2"});
          rows.add(new String[]{"1"});
        
            for (String[] now : rows) {
            System.out.println(now);
        }
}
}
```

I am receiving this output in console can anyone help how to print the dynamically changing length of array.

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@372f7a8d

[Ljava.lang.String;@2f92e0f4

[Ljava.lang.String;@28a418fc
```

Comment: Try using `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(now));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another loop inside the first loop since you have an array list of array

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an output like this because you are trying to print an String array reference, instead of string.Try the below code.

```
public class list{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

         ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
          rows.add(new String[]{"1","2","3"});
          rows.add(new String[]{"1","2"});
          rows.add(new String[]{"1"});
        
          for (String[] now : rows) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < now.length ; i++){//Printing the current array elements 
                System.out.println(now[i]);
            }
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the elements of the arrays:

Solution 1:

```
for (String[] now : rows) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(now));
}
```

Solution 2:

```
for (String[] now : rows) {
      for (String i : now) {
            System.out.println(i);
      }
}
```